# Do rectangles overlap, not overlap, or are the same?

Tags: python-3.x

> If one or more coordinates from r1 & r2 are the same, then ("The rectangles do overlap.")
>
> If no coordinates are the same, then ("The rectangles do not overlap.")
>
> If all coordinates are the same, then ("The rectangles are the same.")

So, when all coordinates are the same, my code prints out `"The rectangles do overlap."` along with `"The rectangles are the same."` -- but I just want it to print `"The rectangles are the same."`. How can it be done?

```
shape = input("Select (rectangle / circle): ")


if shape == "rectangle":

x1 = float(input("Enter rectangle A's left coordinate: "))
x2 = float(input("Enter rectangle A's right coordinate: "))
y1 = float(input("Enter rectangle A's top coordinate: "))
y2 = float(input("Enter rectangle A's bottom coordinate: "))

x01 = float(input("Enter rectangle B's left coordinate: "))
x02 = float(input("Enter rectangle B's right coordinate: "))
y01 = float(input("Enter rectangle B's top coordinate: "))
y02 = float(input("Enter rectangle B's bottom coordinate: "))

r1 = (int(x1), int(x2), int(y1), int(y2))
r2 = (int(x01), int(x02), int(y01), int(y02))

if any(item in r1 for item in r2):
    print("The rectangles do overlap.")
    
if all(item in r1 for item in r2):
    print("The rectangles are the same.")
            
else:
    print("The rectangles do not overlap.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the fact that if `all(...)` is true, `any(...)` will also be true. Just change the order of `if` statements and use `elif`:

```
if all(item in r1 for item in r2):
    print("The rectangles are the same.")
elif any(item in r1 for item in r2):
    print("The rectangles do overlap.")
else:
    print("The rectangles do not overlap.")
```